# Removing asymptotes from y=sec(x)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to draw the graph of *y* = sec(*x* ), see below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[ymax=10,ymin=-10]
\addplot[color=red,domain=-360:360,samples=101,unbounded coords=jump]
{sec(x)};
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis 
cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis 
cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives the below output:

[image]

How do I remove the vertical red lines from  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[ymax=10,ymin=-10]
\addplot[color=red,domain=-360:360,samples=400,restrict y to domain=-15:15]
{sec(x)};
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis 
cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis 
cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the option `restrict y to domain=-10:10` it should give the result you want... but the samples have to be huge for this to work... So I changed it to `-15:15` and just increased a little bit the samples. The output is like yours without the asymptotes.

Answer (score 1):

what about drawing graph by 90 degree domains segments?

```
    \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymax=10,ymin=-10,
    samples=30
            ]
    \foreach \i in {-360,-270,...,270}
\addplot[color=red,domain=\i:\i+90] {sec(x)};
\draw[ultra thin]
    (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]